# Expect HTTP status 301 but always got status 200 from HttpURLConnection's getResponseCode()

Tags: httpurlconnection, http-status-code-301

Upon sending an HTTP POST request to secured URL and receiving the status code, my application needs to decide whether to output the response or, in case of redirect, send a HTTP GET request to the URL specified in the header "Location".

This works fine for at least one of the URL's of a log in page, which returns HTTP status code 302 with a redirect location information to its home page. My application then do a GET on the home page location. So far so good.

Upon sending POST request to this one problematic URL of another login page, however, I always get back an HTTP 200 from getResponseCode() with the log in page itself as a content result. The POST request was sent with correct log in information and the server response with 301, at least I could check that with a Firefox browser's plugin (RESTClient).

With RESTClient plugin, I get an HTTP 301 and the response body (the home page) back as expected. Below are response headers I got when I test with RESTClient:

> Status Code: 301 Moved Permanently Cache-Control: private
>   Content-Length: 62718 Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 Date:
>   Wed, 30 Dec 2015 15:40:57 GMT Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5 Set-Cookie:
>   osVisit=55754609-0612-4846-97af-8b7dff36b56e; expires=Wed, 30-Dec-2015
>   16:10:56 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly pageLoadedFromBrowserCache=false;
>   path=/ X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>   X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge,chrome=1

Does anybody have a clue what is going one here?

Answer (score -1):

@Marin,

if you do **not** want to automatically follow the redirect you need to tell the UrlConnection by setting the followRedirects (`setFollowRedirects(true)`) or instanceFollowRedirects (`setInstanceFollowRedirects(true)`). Otherwise the post will do the redirect automatically, and you will get the http 200.

Hope this will help,
Ivar

Comment: I tried that - settng setInstanceFollowRedirects, both true and false, just to check the effect, but no effect at all - I still get 200 OK for the the POST login. In fact, I think the problem lies somewhere else because, if I should have to call setInstanceFollowRedirects, then I would expect the other POST login not to work without the setting, but it does. I just can't figure out yet, where the problem lies.